# How to Fill a Datatable with a tab delimited text file in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to fill a DataTable with a tab delimited Text file. The text file contains data as follows:

```
Name   Id   Place
Sam    2001   USA
Raja    3455   India
Allan    90101   Canada
```

When I use `OleDBConnection` to import the text file into the DataTable, I am getting data in DataTable as follows:

```
Name_Id_Place
Sam2001USA
Raja3455India
Allan90101Canada
```

The actual text file has 3 columns and 3 rows, but in the DataTable I got all 3 columns as a single column `Name_Id_Place`.

Can anyone tell me the solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you post some sample code please.

Answer (score 4):

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //create a data table and add the column's
        DataTable table = new DataTable("table_name");
        table.Columns.Add("name", typeof (String));
        table.Columns.Add("id", typeof (Int32));
        table.Columns.Add("place", typeof (String));

        //start reading the textfile
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file_to_read");
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] items = line.Split('\t');
            //make sure it has 3 items
            if (items.Length == 3)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row["name"] = items[0];
                row["id"] = Int32.Parse(items[1]);
                row["place"] = items[2];
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();

        // make use of the table


        // when use is done dispose it
        table.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What can do if the text file contains 1000s of rows?

Comment: @VinothSrinivasan - i guess till thousand it would be ok, can say if it cross, 50K or something!

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you reading data from text file in right way, only problem I see that your used Provider cannot understand where a end of column, that why read all row as one column

I had exact same result when trying read data from text file with OleDBConnection.

In my connectionstring as Provider I used:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
```

If you used same then you need only change "Format" options for this provider in Windows registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Jet \ 4.0 \ Engines \ Text
```

Then modify "Format" key to value="TabDelimited"

or if you want use some other delimiter character(for example ";")
then Format = "Delimited(;)"

Comment: Thank you But I couldn't find the option Jet under Microsoft in the Registry. Besides I want to load a large data to SQL table through DataTable. So Initially I load DataTable from a tab delimited text file which contains 1000s of rows. Please help me to how to do that?

Comment: I use the OLEDB connection string as follows @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= |DataDirectory|;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'"

Comment: What system you have, 64-bit or 32-bit system?

Comment: @Vinoth Srivivasan if you got readen data from your text file by OleDB, that mean your PC must have register for this... Sorry cannot find solution for this now. Only I know that OleDB not supported by 64-bit system.

Comment: @Vinoth Srivivasan check this link [support.microsoft.com/kb/252444](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252444)

Comment: I could read excel files using OLEDB, then why can't I read Text files? I am using MSWindows XP Prof Version 2002 Service Pack 2(32 bit).

Comment: You need to inform in someway OLEDB about Delimited sign.(Is it TAB, or Space or period...)